# Does the Entity Framework have an equivalent of DataContext.GetTable<TEntity> from Linq2Sql (ObjectContext.CreateQuery<T>?)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm looking for an equivalent of the `DataContext.GetTable<TEntity>` in Entity Framework.
I've found the `ObjectContext.CreateQuery<T>` method but it is different from `DataContext.GetTable<TEntity>` since it needs a querystring to work.

Is there a way to get an IQueryable object for a table using the entity type without specifying the querystring?

`*EDIT: Added code snippet*`
This is a snippet of a Repository class I've implemented that works with linq2sql. I can't use  `ObjectContext.[TableName]` because it wouldn't be generic anymore.

```
public class BaseRepository<TClass> : IDisposable
        where TClass : class
    {
        protected BaseRepository(DataContext database)
        {
            _database = database;
        }
        ...

        public IQueryable<TClass> GetAllEntities()
        {
            IQueryable<TClass> entities = _database.GetTable<TClass>();
            return entities;
        }

        public IQueryable<TClass> GetEntities(Expression<Func<TClass, bool>> condition)
        {  
            IQueryable<TClass> table = _database.GetTable<TClass>();
            return table.Where(condition);    
        }
```

`*EDIT: Added my solution (so far..)*`
This is what I'm using:

```
public IQueryable<TClass> GetEntities(Expression<Func<TClass, bool>> condition)
{  
    IQueryable<TClass> table = _database.CreateQuery<TClass>(typeof(TClass).Name);
    return table.Where(condition);    
}
```

This works as long as the class name is the same of the table name. This will became a problem for me when I'll start using different objects for the same table.

I hope I've been clear, thanks in advance,
Marco :)

Comment: Marco B, have you found a solution? I have the same problem and even passing "[EntitySet]" as parameter to CreateQuery I can't get it working.

Comment: I found this answer first, and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263083/gettable-equivalent-for-objectcontext) after that. It seems that the second answer has a much easier way of doing this that resembles `GetTable` from Linq2SQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the EF designer itself uses `CreateQuery` with hard-coded strings for the static references.  If you dig into the designer file you'll see something like this:

```
public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Customers> Customers
{
    get
    {
        if ((this._Customers == null))
        {
            this._Customers = base.CreateQuery<Customers>("[Customers]");
        }
        return this._Customers;
    }
}

private global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Customers> _Customers;
```

Technically there's no perfect solution because you can use the same entity type for different entity sets.  But you can give it the old college try:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetEntities<TEntity>()
{
    Type t = typeof(TEntity);
    var edmAttr = (EdmEntityTypeAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t,
        typeof(EdmEntityTypeAttribute), false);
    if (edmAttr == null)  // Fall back to the naive way
    {
        return context.CreateQuery<TEntity>(t.Name);
    }
    var ec = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(
        context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
    var entityType = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetType(edmAttr.Name,
        edmAttr.NamespaceName, DataSpace.CSpace);
    var es = ec.BaseEntitySets.First(es => es.ElementType == entityType);
    return context.CreateQuery<TEntity>(es.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine!

By chance today I found a similar solution in the kigg project on codeplex (http://kigg.codeplex.com).

Comment: Trying to use this code, but the problem is that BaseEntitySets.First is not IQueryable, so I don't see how others got this example working.

Comment: I think this question needs updating.  It seems that the person asking the Question accepted an Answer that he is only using part of, so the Answer is confusing.  In reality the Questioner is only using the `return context.CreateQuery<TEntity>(t.Name);` code which I did not notice and spent a couple hours trying to get the accepted Answer to work.  As soon as I switched to using the CreateQuery method ONLY it works perfectly.

Comment: @James: Forgot one line of code. You just need to create a query with the `Name` from the `EntitySetBase`. I doubt that the OP stuck only with the naive solution of using the type name - that will break with any customization. Please relax, I know it's frustrating to try to implement an answer with a mistake in it, but that does not mean everything else is WRONG WRONG WRONG.

Comment: @Aaronaught: Definitely wasn't saying this was wrong, just that as the accepted answer it didn't work and wasn't actually what the Questioner meant.
Thanks for the update!

Comment: @Aaronaught: Actually, if you have time I would love if you could update your answer a little.  I don't quite even understand the difference in the 2 CreateQueries.  Possibly because mine never hits the first and I'm not sure what type of object would do that.

Comment: Too many comments I know but I think I get it now.  If the Entity Type is not the same Table Name?  Meaning "Customer_Object" vs. "Customer_Table" yes?  So if our entity names are always the same as the table name, all we really need is the CreateQuery line?

Comment: @James: Right. So you can see how that won't always be the case, particularly if you pluralize table names (which I almost always do).

Answer (score 1):

```
public IQueryable GetTable<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    return context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not missing the point, but wouldn't it be:

```
ObjectContext.TableName
```

Where TableName is the EntitySet of the type you want to work with.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to use the table name because I want to have a generic way of accessing the table.
I added a code snippet from my class to better explain what I'd like to achieve.
The only solution I can imagine right now is to use the ObjectContext.CreateQuery<T> method changing a bit the structure of my generic class passing to the constructor also the TableName.