# Using EntityFramework, code-first (CTP5), how do you create the database?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

Background:
I have LINQ-to-SQL code and all my objects are POCO (plain old CLR objects) that use attributes/data annotations. I have no mapping files. I am migrating to Entity Framework and would like to use "Code-First" to also generate my database from my domain model (in code). I have no .edmx, no .ssdl, etc. type meta files.

I'm looking for the LINQ-to-SQL equivalent of something like this:

```
DataContext context = new DataContext(connString)
context.GetTable<MyEntity>();
context.CreateDatabase();
```

Someone asked a similar question here
[Does the Entity Framework have an equivalent of DataContext.GetTable<TEntity> from Linq2Sql (ObjectContext.CreateQuery<T>?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190203/does-the-entity-framework-have-an-equivalent-of-datacontext-gettabletentity-fro)

so my code now looks like this:

```
ObjectContext oContext = new ObjectContext(connectionString);
if (oContext.DatabaseExists()) oContext.DeleteDatabase();
oContext.CreateQuery<StockOrder>(typeof(StockOrder).Name);
oContext.CreateDatabase();
```

The problem I am facing now is -- my connection string has to be an "EntityConnectionString", which is different(!) than my current LINQ-2-SQL connection string I am using.  I feel like I'm going down the wrong path.

Is this even the way to do it? Or maybe EF4 just doesn't support this yet? I hope I'm wrong, otherwise, I will be (like others) severely disappointed with EF4.

Thanks
Ray

Answer (score 0):

Use the [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder(VS.90).aspx) class to create a correct connection.
The code will look like the following:

```
EntityConnectionStringBuilder escb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
escb.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";  
escb.ProviderConnectionString = connString;  
escb.Metadata = "Model1.csdl|Model1.ssdl|Model1.msl"; //set the correct metadata path here  
connString = escb.ToString(); //Here is the correct connection string
```

**UPD:** Here is a Code First sample:

```
  class Program {  
    static void Main(string[] args) {  

      DbDatabase.DefaultConnectionFactory = new System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlConnectionFactory("Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI");  
      DbDatabase.SetInitializer<StockContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<StockContext>());  
      StockContext oContext = new StockContext();  
      oContext.StockOrders.Add(new StockOrder{ StockOrderID = 2, Name = "test"});  
      oContext.SaveChanges();  
    }  
  }  

  public class StockOrder {  

    public int StockOrderID { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
  }  

  public class StockContext : DbContext {  

    public DbSet<StockOrder> StockOrders { get; set; }  
  }
```

Comment: But I am using the code-first (not model first) approach, and I'm using POCO objects with attributes and data annotations. My understanding is that we do NOT have these meta data files. Otherwise, how do they relate and how do I create them?