# Generically return an item from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-4

I have a situation where a website can ask for data from my database based on a string (don't worry - I'm protecting against SQL injections). For various reasons, I would like to have a single method which returns back the object (from EF) that the user expects (which, ultimately, comes back through a partial page).

I'm thinking something like this:

```
public <GenericType?> GetObject(int id, string typeName) {
  switch(typeName) {
    case "Type1":
      return db.Type1s.SingleOrDefault(t => t.TypeID == id);
    case "Type2":
      return db.Type2.SingleOrDefault(t => t.TypeID == id);
    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this? (What I am trying to avoid is having to do the switch statement earlier and then call the specific Repository method because I would then have to repeat code and do this a number of times.)

Comment: I'd love to recommend a dynamic solution, but dynamic objects cannot dispatch extension methods (like `IEnumerable<T>.Where`) and expression trees cannot have dynamic operations.

Comment: Take a look at [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106), formerly called "ADO.NET Data Services".

Comment: Adam - I'm sure this can be achieved using expression trees...

Comment: @flesh - I knew you could, but I had no idea how easy it was.  I need to really get into Expression Trees in depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateQuery<T>` might be what you need.

[Does the Entity Framework have an equivalent of DataContext.GetTable<TEntity> from Linq2Sql (ObjectContext.CreateQuery<T>?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190203/does-the-entity-framework-have-an-equivalent-of-datacontext-gettabletentity-fro)

Is there any way you can get all the possible types you'd be passing in to comport with a particular interface that has this TypeID property on it?  If so, how about:

```
    public T GetResult<T>(int id, string typeName) where T : IClassWithTypeID {
        YourEntities db = new YourEntities();
        var result = db.CreateQuery<T>(String.Format("[{0}]", typeName));

        return result.Single(t => t.TypeID == id);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Practically speaking, any kind of generalized report generator / query executor / etc. is probably better served with direct SQL queries than trying to fit your dynamic logic into EF or LINQ.

Comment: I'm *not* the one who downvoted you - though I certainly disagree that dynamic SQL is preferable to a Generic solution.

Comment: @Adam: I didn't say it was preferable.  But I've been down this road multiple times.  You fight and fight against the language to accomplish your task.  I'm just suggesting it might be the wrong approach practically speaking.

Comment: Yeah - fair enough. If he can't get an interface in there like I suggested, then some SQL will probably be better than whatever voodoo an EF guru suggests. +1

Comment: @Adam: Thanks. I reworded it a little better and toned down my emotion :)

Comment: You may be correct, but his use case is very simple and just as efficient as hand rolled sql.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
    public T GetResult<T>(int id, string typeName) {
        AccrualTrackingEntities db = new AccrualTrackingEntities();
        var result = db.CreateQuery<T>(String.Format("[{0}]", typeName));

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(param, "TypeID"),
                Expression.Constant(id)),
            param);

        return result.Single(lambda);
    }
```

I guess manually stringing together an Expression tree isn't as hard as I thought it was.

Comment: Could you determine what the type name was from `T` and eliminate a parameter?

Comment: *Maybe* - `typeof(T).Name` will return (in case) "Invoice" while EF is expecting the name of the ObjectSet, which is "Invoices"  If all of *your* types can be pluralized correctly by tacking on an S, then you should be able to.  Note however that if you have an entity of type Person, the collection name will likely be People.

Comment: In that case you can use System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService. Which is what EF used to create the plural of your type. It's not that important really, but generally I really dislike magic strings.

Answer (score 0):

Considering how things will look when you call this method...presumably it would look something like this:

```
object obj = GetObject(257, "Type1");
```

I can't think of a way to make the type of the returned value more specific, because objects in the EF don't have a common base class, neither do they implement a common interface. Of course, you could make them implement such an interface (as Adam suggests, though with a different purpose), and then rewrite your method like this:

```
public IMyInterface GetObject(int id, string typeName) {
    switch(typeName) {
        case "Type1":
            return (IMyInterface)db.Type1s.SingleOrDefault(t => t.TypeID == id);
        case "Type2":
            return (IMyInterface)db.Type2.SingleOrDefault(t => t.TypeID == id);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Then your calling code would look like this:

```
IMyInterface intf = GetObject(257, "Type1");
intf.DoSomethingHelpful();
```

Of course, my guess at your calling code may be way off.