# C# Linq-to-SQL Create a Generic Repository

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern

I have a few repositories that all generally look like this

```
public class DepartmentsRepository
{
    private PersonnelActionFormDataContext db = new PersonnelActionFormDataContext();

    /// <summary>
    /// returns all departments
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>an iquerable of all departments</returns>
    public IQueryable<Department> GetAll()
    {
        return db.Departments;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get department by id
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">id of the department</param>
    /// <returns>a null department if nothing is found</returns>
    public Department Get(int id)
    {
        return db.Departments.SingleOrDefault(d => d.id == id);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get department by department name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="department">name of the department</param>
    /// <returns>a null department if nothing is found</returns>
    public Department Get(string department)
    {
        return db.Departments.SingleOrDefault(d => d.DepartmentName == department);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a department
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="department"></param>
    public void Add(Department department)
    {
        db.Departments.InsertOnSubmit(department);
    }
```

I'd like to have some sort of generic base class that could save me some typing, so I started here

```
 public class GenericRepository<T>
{
    private PersonnelActionFormDataContext db = new PersonnelActionFormDataContext();

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return db.
    }
}
```

how do I access the collection of Ts to return them?  Is this possible?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what is db - is this linq-to-sql, or entity framework?

Comment: That actually makes it easier - see my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Linq-to-SQL this should work:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetResultL2S<T>() where T : class {
    MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
    return db.GetTable<T>();
}
```

Or, if you're using Entity Framework, then you'd do something like:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetResultEF<T>() {
    YourEntities db = new YourEntities();
    return db.CreateQuery<T>(String.Format("[{0}s]", typeof(T).Name));
}
```

That assumes your entity sets can be pluralized by tacking an s on.  If that's not the case, then check out `System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService`

Comment: public T Get<T>(int id) where T : class
        {
            return db.GetTable<T>().SingleOrDefault(d => d.id == id);
        }
something like this doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: How could it?  C# doesn't know that whatever T is has an id property on it.  You'd have to say where T : class, ISomeInterfaceWithAnIdPropertyOnIt

Comment: Or if an interface like that's not available, you'd have to build an expression tree from scratch, which can get obtuse.  Here's a simple example (tested only with EF, not L2S) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046917/generically-return-an-item-from-entity-framework/5047252#5047252

Comment: AHHH, good looking out. OK...so, do I have to do something like create partial classes for my dbcontext objects and then and implement a iEntity with a id property and then do something like this, where T : iEntity...then these will work.  Is there a better way?

Comment: If you want to do that for ALL your entities, then I'd just build an expression tree - I'd hate to create N partial classes just to stick in an id property

Comment: The linked answer above should be able to be adapted with little effort

Comment: Here is a generic primary key function for L2S that I wrote a while back if you are having trouble converting the EF one. [http://csainty.blogspot.com/2008/04/linq-to-sql-generic-primary-key.html](http://csainty.blogspot.com/2008/04/linq-to-sql-generic-primary-key.html)

Comment: @Chris Sainty, that's money...I really like that.  Can we modify it to take in a parameter value and name and find by that?

Comment: @jim, of course you can, but when you start doing things like that, why not just use the typed objects that linq provides for you, and use a simple lambda, rather than passing in a string-based property name in with a value, and reflecting to build the right expression tree?

Comment: Just to be clear - searching by id specifically is a rather common thing to do, so it probably makes sense in that case (which is why @chris wrote that extension method) - my last comment was WRT doing this sort of thing for more advanced queries

Comment: @Adam, will you edit your answer, I wanted to give you an upvote but for some reason I gave you a downvote and now it won't let me fix that unless you edit the answer.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks bud, I'll be out of Vote Cap hell in 2 hours. :)