# GetTable equivalent for ObjectContext

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, objectcontext

I was previously using a DataContext which had a GetTable(type) method to get tables generically.  Example:

```
context.GetTable(myObject.GetType());
```

Recently my team decided to switch to using ObjectContext with the Entity Framework.  Is there a way to get tables by the entity name similar to DataContexts GetTable method without having to specify a specific type?  It has to be generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed a very simple way to do this, like so:

```
public IQueryable GetTable<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    return context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
}
```

Now if I create a `Person` object and pass to it the generic method, the variable below 'allPeople' will be an `IQueryable` of people from my database which you can iterate though.

```
Person person = new Person();
IQueryable allPeople = GetTable(person);
```