# Lambda expression casting

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, entity-framework-5

How can I cast from

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate
```

to

```
Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>> predicate
```

?

Couldn't find a way so far. Or at least create a new `Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>>` by using the first one's string representation of the predicate.

If it helps, `T` is limited to types implementing `ISomeInterface`, and `SomeType` implements it.

**LE: further clarification**

The interface is something like:

```
public interface ICacheable
{
    List<T> GetObjects<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : ICacheable;
}
```

then you have

```
public partial class Video : ICacheable
{
    public List<T> GetObjects<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : ICacheable
    {
        // implementation here that returns the actual List<Video>
        // but when I try to query the dbcontext I can't pass a predicate with type T, I have to cast it somehow
        List<Video> videos = db.Videos.Where(predicate).ToList(); // not working
    }
}
```

then you have:

```
public class RedisCache
{
    public List<T> GetList<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : ICacheable
    {
        List<T> objList = // get objects from cache store here
        if(objList == null)
        {
            List<T> objList = GetObjects<T>(predicate);
            // cache the result next
        }
        return objList;
    }
}
```

I use the above from any class like so:

```
// If the list is not found, the cache store automatically retrieves 
// and caches the data based on the methods enforced by the interface
// The overall structure and logic has more to it. 
List<Video> videos = redisCache.GetList<Video>(v => v.Title.Contains("some text"));
List<Image> images = redisCache.GetList<Image>(v => v.Title.Contains("another text"));
```

And I would extend this to any type of object I need to be cachable, with methods that will allow the Cache store to automatically retrieve an entity or list of entities if they are not found in cache. I might be doing this completely wrong though.

Comment: Well what would you expect to happen if it were passed an implementation of `ISomeInterface` which *isn't* `SomeType`?

Comment: On second thought I 'm not sure this is a dupe, but you may want to read that question anyway. If you need to do anything more than dumb type substitution, my condolences.

Comment: @Jon it is indeed an exact duplicate.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I added more details just in case, I'm going to look into the duplicate, I expected to be simpler though. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not up to scratch on my Entity Framework, but I know that the `DatabaseContext` within LINQ has a `GetTable<T>` which returns the table based on the generic. If "[GetTable equivalent for ObjectContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263083/gettable-equivalent-for-objectcontext)" is anything to go by, it's also available in EF?

To make your statement truly generic, you could try this:

```
public MyBaseObject<T>
{
    public List<T> GetObjects<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : ICacheable
    {
        return db.CreateObjectSet<T>().Where(predicate).ToList();
    }
}

public partial class Image : MyBaseObject<Image>, ICacheable
{
}

public partial class Video : MyBaseObject<Video>, ICacheable
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something (extremely) basic which, I hope, might help you in the process of caching using generics.

```
// ICacheable interface is used as a flag for cacheable classes
public interface ICacheable
{
}

// Videos and Images are ICacheable
public class Video : ICacheable
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
}

public class Image : ICacheable
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
}

// CacheStore will keep all objects loaded for a class, 
// as well as the hashcodes of the predicates used to load these objects
public class CacheStore<T> where T : ICacheable
{
    static List<T> loadedObjects = new List<T>();
    static List<int> loadedPredicatesHashCodes = new List<int>();

    public static List<T> GetObjects(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) 
    {

        if (loadedPredicatesHashCodes.Contains(predicate.GetHashCode<T>()))
            // objects corresponding to this predicate are in the cache, filter all cached objects with predicate
            return loadedObjects.Where(predicate.Compile()).ToList();
        else
            return null;
    }

    // Store objects in the cache, as well as the predicates used to load them    
    public static void StoreObjects(List<T> objects, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var hashCode = predicate.GetHashCode<T>();
        if (!loadedPredicatesHashCodes.Contains(hashCode))
        {
            loadedPredicatesHashCodes.Add(hashCode);
            loadedObjects = loadedObjects.Union(objects).ToList();
        }
    }
}

// DbLoader for objets of a given class
public class DbStore<T> where T : ICacheable
{
    public static List<T> GetDbObjects(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return new List<T>(); // in real life, load objects from  Db, with predicate
    }
}

// your redis cache
public class RedisCache
{
    public static List<T> GetList<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T:ICacheable
    {
        // try to load from cache
        var objList = CacheStore<T>.GetObjects(predicate);
        if(objList == null)
        {
            // cache does not contains objects, load from db
            objList = DbStore<T>.GetDbObjects(predicate);
            // store in cache
            CacheStore<T>.StoreObjects(objList,predicate);
        }
        return objList;
    }
}

// example of using cache
public class useRedisCache
{
    List<Video> videos = RedisCache.GetList<Video>(v => v.Title.Contains("some text"));
    List<Image> images = RedisCache.GetList<Image>(i => i.Title.Contains("another text"));
}

// utility for serializing a predicate and get a hashcode (might be useless, depending on .Equals result on two equivalent predicates)
public static class PredicateSerializer
{
    public static int GetHashCode<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : ICacheable
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Expression<Func<T, bool>>));
        var strw = new StringWriter();
        var sw = XmlWriter.Create(strw);
        serializer.Serialize(sw, predicate);
        sw.Close();
        return strw.ToString().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```