# How to get table dynamic in EntityFramework 5

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-5

I'm switching form LINQ to SQL to EntityFramework 5. In LINQ to SQL I have used this function, to get a table just by its type (VB-Code):

```
Dim type As Type = myObject.GetType()
Dim context As MyEntities = New MyEntities()
query = context.GetTable(type).AsQueryable()
```

Now I'm searching for an equal method in EF5. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263083/gettable-equivalent-for-objectcontext) answer on SO, but my context doesn't has a method called `CreateObjectSet`. Is this because of difference between EF4 and EF5, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263083/gettable-equivalent-for-objectcontext) answer I found out that I can use `Set` instead of `CreateObjectSet`:

```
Public Function GetTable(Of T As Class)(entity As T) As IQueryable
    Return dbContext.Set(Of T)()
End Function
```

Comment: Hello ! Using your idea , is it possible on entity framework to create a query where the table name is a string name : For example I have a table name : MyEntity as a string. Is it possible to create a query like : From t in GetTable(????)  Where t.id=7 select t ?

Comment: You can use reflection for this: `dbContext.Set(Type.GetType("MyNamespace.MyEntity"));`